# Attribute error Odoo

Tags: odoo

Just installed Odoo v8 in win7, dumped and imported db from another machine/installation, when i click one receipt i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\account\account_invoice.py", line 343, in fields_view_get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\mail\mail_thread.py", line 348, in fields_view_get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 1549, in fields_view_get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 845, in postprocess_and_fields
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170910\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 368, in raise_view_error
AttributeError: Field `vertical_comp` does not exist

Error context:
View `account.invoice.form`
[view_id: 469, xml_id: account.invoice_form, model: account.invoice, parent_id: n/a]
```

I can see Vertical_comp field here: tabase structure > fields.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you also reinstall all the modules from your former installation ?

Comment: Hello, no I didn't. The old installation run in a Linux server this one in a local windows machine, i have just dumped the db.  can i backup these modules from linux and reinstall in win? or maybe i just need to check which modules are installed and download them again? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should redownload them if possible. If you cannot then you can try to get them from your linux installation.

Comment: Where can I find and compare the installed modules? in configuration local modules seems to be pretty the same between the two installations.  many thanks

Comment: If there is no différences in the `addons/` directory, then it's possible that the field `vertical_comp` was hard coded into an existing module. You can try to run the command in the `addons/` directory (in your old server) : `find . -exec grep -Hn 'vertical_comp = ' {} 2>/dev/null \;`. This command will try to find the definition and where this field is used, and in which module.

Comment: @Unatiel error was caused by missing modules as you said. Thanks